# Adding mod_rewrite Rules to .htaccess in WordPress

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the mod rewrite rule in WordPress without directly modifying the *.htaccess* file. It seems to be possible according to this web page: [Adding mod_rewrite Rules to .htaccess in WordPress](http://kovshenin.com/2009/adding-mod_rewrite-rules-to-htaccess-in-wordpress/). I followed the instruction and created a plugin as follows. I saved the file name as *sample-mod-rewrite.php*.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Mod Rewrite  */

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$this, 'generate_rewrite_rules'));
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', array(&$this, 'mod_rewrite_rules'));
function generate_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $non_wp_rules = array(
        'simple-redirect/?$plugin_name' => 'http://google.com',
        'one-more-redirect/?$plugin_name' => 'http://yahoo.com'
    );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
}
function mod_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $rules = preg_replace('/^(RewriteRule ^.*+/?$)plugin_name (/)(.*) ([QSA,L])$/im', '1 3 [R=301,L]', $rules);
    return $rules;
}
```

How is it supposed to work? After activating the plugin, when I access *http://siteurl/simple-redirect/?sample-mod-rewrite* or *http://siteurl/simple-redirect/?sample-mod-rewrite.php* the browser just displays the 404 error, "Object not found!." I think I must be doing something wrong.

The part `array(&$this, 'generate_rewrite_rules')` looks like passing a class method but the web page does not tell anything about creating a class. It should be really simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your plugin do not use a class, you should use :

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'mod_rewrite_rules');
```

The regexp used in `mod_rewrite_rules` is not really correct, but I can't give you a better one since I don't know what you really want to achieve.

And don't forget to regenerate your `.htaccess` file.

**EDIT** :

To regenerate your `.htaccess` file, you simply have to access your permalinks settings.

The function `generate_rewrite_rules` will add the following rules in `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteRule ^simple-redirect/?$plugin_name /wordpress/http://google.com [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^one-more-redirect/?$plugin_name /wordpress/http://yahoo.com [QSA,L]
```

And the goal of `mod_rewrite_rules` function is to correct these rules, you can try :

```
$rules = preg_replace('#^(RewriteRule \^.*/\?\$)plugin_name .*(http://.*) \[QSA,L\]#mi', '$1 $2 [R=301,L]', $rules);
```

Then the rules will be :

```
RewriteRule ^simple-redirect/?$ http://google.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^one-more-redirect/?$ http://yahoo.com [R=301,L]
```

So accessing `siteurl/simple-redirect/` will redirect to `google.com` ...

Comment: Thanks for correcting the parameters. `I can't give you a better one since I don't know what you really want to achieve.` - Okay, I try to be clear as possible. I'm trying to see how mod rewrite rules work in WordPress so I need a working example to analyze the code by breaking it down. The sample plugin I posted should redirect the page to google or yahoo when let's say _http://siteurl/simple-redirect/?sample-mod-rewrite=true_ is accessed. Regarding regenerating the `.htaccess` file, how do I do it? It is simply done by saving the option in the permalink settings page?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. `To regenerate your .htaccess file, you simply have to access your permalinks settings.` - so if I want to implement it in a distributed plugin, is it not practical since the user manually has to save the permalink settings? Also, it seems if the permalink is set to the default, it doesn't add the rules to `.htaccess`. I'm wondering what `$plugin_name` in the regex pattern is for by the way.

Comment: About `.htaccess` generation, you should ask another question. About `$plugin_name` you should read carefully the tutorial you found : "*I used the string ‘plugin_name’ in every rule just to make sure that I don’t edit anyone else’s rewrite rules further on*"

Comment: `"I used the string ‘plugin_name’ in every rule just to make sure that I don’t edit anyone else’s rewrite rules further on"` - It looks like a PHP variable though. So is the `$` sign nothing to do with PHP here but just used to differentiate it from other query strings?

Comment: Not from *other query string*, from other rules. And `$plugin_name` is not a variable since it is inside a simple quote string.

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting the working complete code. I wrapped it in a class.

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample Mod Rewrite  */

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', array(new custom_mod_rewrite, "generate_rewrite_rules"));

class custom_mod_rewrite {
    function __construct() {
        $this->wp_rewrite = & $GLOBALS["wp_rewrite"];
    }
    function generate_rewrite_rules() {

        $non_wp_rules = array(
            'simple-redirect/?$plugin_name' => 'http://google.com',
            'one-more-redirect/?$plugin_name' => 'http://yahoo.com'
        );

        $this->wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $non_wp_rules + $this->wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
        add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', array(&$this, "mod_rewrite_rules"));
    }
    function mod_rewrite_rules($rules) {
        return preg_replace('#^(RewriteRule \^.*/)\?\$plugin_name .*(http://.*) \[QSA,L\]#mi', '$1 $2 [R=301,L]', $rules);
    }
}
```